# How to run an android test

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

I am trying to run my first android test

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.lenabru.activities.MainActivity;

/**
 * @author Lena Sep 16, 2013, 2013 at 10:02:19 PM
 */
public class MainActivityUnitTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {

    MainActivity activity;
    int buttonId;

    public MainActivityUnitTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent, null, null);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testLayout() {

        buttonId = com.lenabru.R.id.btnLogin;
        assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(buttonId));
        Button view = (Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
        assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "Start", view.getText());
    }


    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

however, i'm getting this exception

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testLayout (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lenabru.ichess.activities.MainActivity
at com.lenabru.test.MainActivityUnitTest.<init>(MainActivityUnitTest.java:26)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:103)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:127)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:55)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:81)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:418)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:399)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:364)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:124)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1006)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: That was not Unit testing but Android Test project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your Application Project is in your Test's project build path.

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem occurs with IntelliJ when using ActionBar support. The fix for this is to add the v4 and v7 support libs as 'Provided' scope, rather than 'Compile' to the test module.